# How can I use Tensorflow in tizen studio?

Tags: tensorflow, x86, tizen

I want to use tensorflow in tizen.

Tizen studio's architecture is x86.
But tensorflow is only 64-bit. 
How can I use tensorflow in tizen studio??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Download packages for target device

- tensorflow
- python
- db4

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp

BASE_URL='http://download.tizen.org/snapshots/tizen/5.0-base/latest/repos/standard/packages/armv7l/'
wget -O - $BASE_URL 2>/dev/null | egrep 'db4-[0-9]' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $BASE_URL{}
wget -O - $BASE_URL 2>/dev/null | egrep 'python-[0-9]' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $BASE_URL{}

UNIFIED_URL='http://download.tizen.org/snapshots/tizen/5.0-unified/latest/repos/standard/packages/armv7l/'
wget -O - $UNIFIED_URL 2>/dev/null | grep 'tensorflow-v' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $UNIFIED_URL{}
```

### Install packages on target device

```
sdb root on; sdb shell 'mount -o remount,rw /'
sdb push *.rpm /tmp

sdb shell 'cd /tmp; rpm -ivh --force db4*.rpm; rpm -ivh --force *python*.rpm; rpm -ivh --force tensorflow*.rpm'

cd ..
rm -r tmp
```

### Download packages needed for building

- tensorflow
- tensorflow-devel
- libpython-2.7
- libgfortran
- libgomp

```
mkdir tmp
cd tmp

BASE_URL='http://download.tizen.org/snapshots/tizen/5.0-base/latest/repos/standard/packages/armv7l/'
wget -O - $BASE_URL 2>/dev/null | grep 'libpython-2.7' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $BASE_URL{}
wget -O - $BASE_URL 2>/dev/null | grep 'libgfortran-' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $BASE_URL{}
wget -O - $BASE_URL 2>/dev/null | grep 'libgomp-' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $BASE_URL{}

UNIFIED_URL='http://download.tizen.org/snapshots/tizen/5.0-unified/latest/repos/standard/packages/armv7l/'
wget -O - $UNIFIED_URL 2>/dev/null | grep 'tensorflow' | grep -v 'lite' | awk -F'"' '{print $2}' | xargs -i wget $UNIFIED_URL{}
```

### Extract header and so files and selectively import to project lib folder

```
ls *.rpm | xargs -i bash -c "rpm2cpio {} | cpio -idmv"

cd usr/lib/
ln -s libpython2.7.so.1.0 libpython2.7.so
ln -s libgfortran.so.3 libgfortran.so

cp libgfortran.so* libgomp.so.1* libpython2.7.so* libpywrap_tensorflow_internal.so ../../../lib/

cd ../include
cp -r tensorflow ../../../inc/

cd ../../..
rm -r tmp
```

### Set up include path in Tizen Studio project

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDb1B.png)

### Set up library path and add libraries to Tizen Studio project

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmuvK.png)

#### Note that if you want to build the project for emulator, you have to use library files for x86 architecture, so you would have to replace "armv7l" in all the URLs above with "i686"

Comment: Or change it to "x86_64" for 64-bit arch.

Comment: hi @David. thank you for your answer.
During execution, I got an error.
when i write sdb root on, i have an error.
'root' is not a known command, 'on' is not a known command...
how can i do it..?

Comment: There was a dependency error during RPM installation.

Answer (score 0):

**Tizen studio is just development tool.

Tizen supports [x86-64(AMD64)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64) and you can use the tensorflow on Tizen.**

If you want to use Tizen with tensorflow, you need to install some packages(`tensorflow`, `python`,...) yourself.

Comment: ok. but tensorflow_cc.so is x86_64. 
and tizen studio's gcc compiler is x86 or arm architecture.
i already have tensorflow_cc.so, tensorflow_framework.so, tensorflow, python ..
how can i use these files in tizen studio..

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford using Tensorflow-Lite, you can use it directly in Tizen-latest. Soon, with Tizen 5.5 M2, there will be Machine Learning APIs that allows app developers to directly plugin .tflite models as well as their own native models (as .so files or as functions) without worrying about importing external libraries.

Anyway, if you want to do it right now, use the Tizen-latest (Tizen:Unified project in build.tizen.org), use tensorflow-lite-dev.rpm package directly or use nnstreamer-capi package, which gives you some easy-to-use interfaces. Note that nnstreamer (https://github.com/nnsuite/nnstreamer ) is going to be the main engine for Tizen-Machine-Learning (backend of its Machine Learning API sets). Although nnstreamer is compatible with Tensorflow (non-lite), Caffe2, PyTorch, ROS, and so on, they are not included in Tizen by default.